# In Bot-framework, I am not able to connect the socket using "Receive activities from the bot"

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

In Bot-framework, I am not able to connect the socket using "Receive activities from the bot" rest client([Refer API Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities))

Please find the below response from "Start a conversation" restful API

```
{
    "conversationId": "BOK3llPHr5I3y2pnAjSkNG",
    "token": "0eM5DHesPHs.dAA.QgBPAEsAMwBsAGwAUABIAHIANQBJADMAeQAyAHAAbgBBAGoAUwBrAE4ARwA.Z0AUwIMr0wE.ZnmgKFRh6Tc.0I6lq2-9FHUq6coAers8OYRgSfTTH5ENgQyzy2r89VU",
    "expires_in": 1800,
    "streamUrl": "wss://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/BOK3llPHr5I3y2pnAjSkNG/stream?watermark=-&t=0eM5DHesPHs.dAA.QgBPAEsAMwBsAGwAUABIAHIANQBJADMAeQAyAHAAbgBBAGoAUwBrAE4ARwA.Z1L1sn8r0wE.iQJtkv2cn6s.iCdU3OtuY3UprEP78UUtImbZ-a4pa7dmDw02kKP_MZk",
    "referenceGrammarId": "a2e8d13d-bcf4-bb58-b85a-b539c4e5a1c4"
}
```

I try to connect the socket with "StreamUrl", but I am unable to connect the socket. Socket return:

> Connection fails.

For socket connection I use `IO socket` library. Before connecting the socket I replace `wss` to `https` in the URL.

Kindly let me know your answer/solution for below questions

1. Whether we need to add any "SSL certificate" for socket connection?
2. Replacement of `wss` to `https` in the URL is correct??

Comment: Where is your bot hosted?

Comment: Have you reviewed the Direct Line Web Sockets samples for Bot Builder? https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLineWebSockets and https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets